# Change text color depending on value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Have the following to pull records from the database:

```
echo "
<tr>
<td valign='top'>" . $row["id"]. "</td>
<td valign='top'>" . $row["fecha"]. "</td>
<td valign='top'>" . $row["numero"]. "</td>
<td valign='top' align='left'>" . $row["cliente"]. "<br>" . $row["addr1"]. "<br>" . $row["addr2"]. "</td>
<td valign='top'>" . $row["cif"]. "</td>
<td valign='top' align='left'>" . $row["trabajo"]. "</td>
<td valign='top' align='left'>&euro; " . $row["cantidad"]. "</td>
<td valign='top'>" . $row["status"]. "</td>
<td valign='top'><h2><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></h2></td>
</tr>";
```

Now when it shows the "status" record there are 2 values (dropdown box on form) "PRO FORMA" and "PAGADO" that I can echo on the results page using " . $row["status"]. "

I want to find out how to change the color of the text depending on the result, PRO FORM in red and PAGADO can stay as is.

Anyone can give me a little push into the right direction?

Comment: I would just repeat the "status" value as a class name on the td that will show it. then add the css for it.

Comment: So long as `$row["status"]` doesn't have any spaces or funny characters. You'd need to run it through a cleaner, or a relational array to turn it into a css class worthy name. So many ways you can go with this. "What have you tried but no success"?

Comment: @OMGDrAcula  that space in 'FRO FORMA'  ? will it work for class? I think he/she should create if statement to check the status and assigned class name to a variable before adding that to `td`

Comment: @SaydFuad
Good catch. You are exactly right! OP can definitely add an if statement then add a class called pro or forma that will change the css!

Comment: If an answer answered your question, accept it, don't add "[SOLVED]" to the question's title.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to change the text color of the table depending on the value contained in the variable `$row['status']`, correct?

For this, an idea is to use the ternary operator in this way:

```
echo "
<tr ".((strcmp($row['status'], 'PAGADO') != 0) ? ('style="color: red;"') : ('')).">
...
</tr>";
```

Here in this example I would only change the first line because I used the algorithm in the first tr, but if you want to apply it to all lines, just use that algorithm in the line where the table tag is.

Comment: Yihaa!!! Thanks! Works great. Added it to one specific <TD> where staus is shown. We should have met 24 hours ago, LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line :-

```
<td valign='top' style='" . (($row['status'] == 'PRO FORM') ? 'color:#f00' : '') . "'>"
```